# Export JasperReport's report to pdf via Servlet or JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports

I have used the following code for exporting a jasper report to a pdf file using JSP.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"application.pdf\"");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");

Connection con;

String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/123";
String uname = "root";
String upass = "";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");      

con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uname, upass);

String report="C:\\Users\\Acer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\jasper\\1.jrxml";
JasperReport jr= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,  null, con);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "application.pdf");
```

When I run this JSP file in *NetBeans*, a message box with the following error appears in the browser:

"File does not begin with '%PDF-'.
Local\EWH_)!50gc#"

This message comes from Adobe Reader.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `When I run this JSP file in netbeans` - What this jsp? I don't see the code for showing message ("File does not begin with ...")

Comment: The above code is used as a scriptlet in a jsp file. (contained within '<% and %>).

Answer (score 2):

Using `exportReportToPdfFile()` is totally wrong: you do not want to create a file, rather export to the response stream. So replace the last line of the snippet with:

```
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nikos! the problem has been resolved. :)

Comment: How i can export a report in ppt?

Answer (score 0):

Seems everyting is ok ,except the last section ie, the export section.

Replace it with

```
//Exporting the report as a PDF
    System.out.println("Exporting pdf");
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "report.pdf");
```